# Query plan in Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I'm executing a query: `"SELECT e.name,d.name FROM emp as e, department as d WHERE e.dept = d.dept;"` in Spanner which works totally fine on the Spanner console.
But when I try to fire the same query using Apache Beam it gives me an error saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Queries with more than one DistributedUnion are currently considered not partitionable. Please view the query plan through the dev console, gcloud or using the API.
```

The Apache Beam code that I'm using is:

```
p.apply(SpannerIO.read()
    .withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)
    .withQuery("SELECT e.name,d.name FROM emp as e, department as d WHERE e.dept = d.dept;"))
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Struct,Struct>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
    {
          System.out.println(c.element().toString());
    }
 }));
```

I tried going through the query execution plan but not sure what exactly is expected when the same thing works fine on the Spanner UI/console.

Answer (score 1):

SpannerIO by default uses the batch API of Google Cloud Spanner (https://batch-spanner.googleapis.com/). The batch API tries to partition your queries into multiple parts that can be fetched in parallel, but your query does not support this. You should try to force the SpannerIO to use the normal Spanner API by calling `SpannerConfig#setHost("https://spanner.googleapis.com")`

Comment: To clarify, changing the host is not enough. SpannerIO uses different query execution path, please follow https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.PartitionQuery for documentation and https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4946

Answer (score 1):

Today, the Cloud Dataflow connector only supports SQL queries where the first operator in the query execution plan is a Distributed Union. Please follow https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector#troubleshooting_unsupported_queries for more information.

In the following Apache Beam 2.5.0 release it will be possible to disable batching using `SpannerIO.read().withBatching(false)`, see more here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3973.